# Check if value exists in Array then save as variable

Tags: php, arrays

Been trying for a while on how to check if a value exists in an array and if so, assign it to a variable to be inserted into the database.

I have the searching working although I can't seem to grab the correct value from the array to which I then need to insert.

Here's where I'm searching for the ID to search by:

```
{
    "questionName": "_questionImgPhoto_176471",
    "questionID": "471",
}
```

Here's the array example:

```
[0]"/insert/ImgID_466.png"
[1]"/insert/ImgID_471.png"
```

I am checking if questionID 471 exists somewhere in the array string, if so, insert that row. I am struggling on that part.

So for the insert on questionID 466, the img with 466 in the string will attach to it and so forth.

As you can see 471 does exist in the array example so it should grab that row, here's a snippet of my code below:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($content->formValuesT); $i++) 
                    { 

                        if(strpos($content->formValuesT[$i]->questionValue, 'blob') !== false )
                            {

                                foreach($content->images_to_upload[$i] as $index => $string) {
                                    if (strpos($string, $content->formValuesT[$i]->questionID) !== FALSE)
                                    {
                                         $file_to_upload = $content->images_to_upload[$i];    
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo "wont insert";
                                    }
                                }

                            }
}
```

Has anyone got some pointers or ideas on how to achieve the above? I just can't wrap my head around the practical side of it! in theory I think this is the correct route.

The $file_to_upload is what will be uploaded per row.

Thanks

Comment: Your first array example is a JSON string/object, not a PHP array.

Comment: Wups just renaming that now, should have reviewed the question a bit better! thanks for spotting that Markus

Comment: I think you want to have `$file_to_upload = $content->images_to_upload[$i][$index];` Or just `$file_to_upload = $string;` is the equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search an array for a specific pattern. Here I made a simple helper function to return the first match or NULL.

```
$imagesToInsert = ["/insert/ImgID_466.png", "/insert/ImgID_471.png"];

$getImageForId = function(int $id, array $images): ?string {
    $matches = preg_grep("/ImgID_{$id}\.png/", $images);
    return $matches ? reset($matches) : null;
};

var_dump($getImageForId(471, $imagesToInsert));
var_dump($getImageForId(466, $imagesToInsert));
var_dump($getImageForId(777, $imagesToInsert));
```

#### Output

```
string(21) "/insert/ImgID_471.png"
string(21) "/insert/ImgID_466.png"
NULL
```

Comment: Perfect Markus, worked well - thanks a ton! marked as answer :)